# Save ID in variable and add style to it

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to highlight randomly a word which is inside a `<p>` tag with the `id=JShighlight`. It should blink one time and then another randomly chosen word should blink.** **I can't add the css style needed to the ID.**

The words are nested in a span with an unique id like `id="one"` oder `id="two"`.
Like:

```
<p id="JShighlight"> <span id="one">Lorem </span><span id="two">Ipsum </span><span id="three">Dolores</span></p>
```

To chose a word randomly, I build an array with the child-nodes of JShighlight. And call it childNodeArray

```
let childNodeArray = document.getElementById('JShighlight').children;
```

Then I randomly chose an index:

```
  let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * childNodeArray.length);
```

The variable name saves the randomly chosen ID.

```
let name = childNodeArray[i].id;
```

To this randomly chosen word /`Id` I want to add a certain style so that this word blinks one time. 
I tried:

```
name.classList.add("blinking");
```

(.blinking is the css-class:

```
.blinking {
    animation: blinkingText 0.6s 1;
    /* animation-iteration-count: 1; */
}
```

)

But it does not work. 
What "works" is:

```
document.getElementById(name).style.color = "red";
```

**Why can I pass a variable as an argument in the latter case and not in the former case?
How can I append a css class to an variable ID?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

`let name = childNodeArray[i].id;`

try

`let name = childNodeArray[i];`

Hope your issue will be resolved;

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, name is a string not an element. 
what you can do is:

```
name = document.getElementById(name);
name.classList.add("blinking");
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Array.from` to convert children DOM list to array of DOM elements. Also remove the `id` attribute before storing the name refer variable.

Please update the below lines.

```
let childNodeArray = Array.from(document.getElementById('JShighlight').children);
let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * childNodeArray.length);
let name = childNodeArray[i];
name.classList.add("blinking");
```